# Can i change the paragraph text and at the same time keep the CSS(the coloring) for the span elements inside the paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

This is the HTML which I'm trying to change and I'm trying to keep the coloring(CSS) for the words wrapped in  tags - Paper and Rock. Basically I want to change the text in the  and the

and keep the CSS(coloring) for the 2  tags.

HTML:

```
    <div class="message">
        <p><span id="result-user">Paper</span> beats <span id="result-comp">Rock</span>!You win!</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #result-user{
        color: rgb(246, 189, 76);
    }
    #result-comp{
        color: rgb(246, 189, 76);
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
    let resultUserMessage_span = document.getElementById('result-user');
    let resultCompMessage_span = document.getElementById('result-comp');
    let resultMessage_p = document.querySelector('.message > p');
    userChoice = "Rock";
    compChoice = "Paper";

    resultMessage_p.innerHTML = `${userChoice} loses to ${compChoice}!You lose!`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert spans with the correct ids when changing the `innerHTML`

```
resultMessage_p.innerHTML = `<span id="result-user">${userChoice}</span> loses to <span id="result-comp">${compChoice}</span>! You lose!`;
```

Comment: With this line of code i am trying to change the whole text in the paragraph which i have stored in the variable - resultMessage_p. But when doing that i also remove the CSS for the spans.

Comment: Oo I see what you mean.

Comment: yeah `innerHTML` recognizes markup so you can use `<span>`s or any other tag while building the text to insert

Comment: Does this mean that the innerHTML in my case removes the spans and keeps only the <p> tag?

Comment: Yeah, if you were to set the innerHTML to an empty string it would completely remove everything inside (including text, spans, images - anything).  That's why we have to put them back when creating the string to insert

Comment: Is it the same with innerText ?

Answer (score 1):

In your function, try

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "<span id="result-user">${userChoice}</span> beats <span id="result-comp">${compChoice}</span>!You lose!";
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this is to wrap your code with the span element as such

```js
resultMessage_p.innerHTML = `<span id="result-user">${userChoice}</span> loses to <span id="result-comp">${compChoice}</span> !You lose!`
```

A better could be to treat your answer modularly by adding spans to each part of your answer and changing the innerHTML depending on the status of the 'game'

```html
<p>
  <span id="result-user">Rock</span>
  <span id="result-status"> loses to </span> 
  <span id="result-comp">Paper</span>!
  <span id="final-result"> You lose!</span>
</p>
```